# How to define number of slots in a Airflow pool

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I'm using Airflow through Cloud Composer (Image: `composer-2.0.29-airflow-2.3.3`). I have defined 5 DAGS that run concurrently with 22 tasks run concurrently (max) distributed among the 5 DAGS. These DAGS are in the default-pool with default number of slots set to 128.
My composer instance has:

- 1 Scheduler: 0.5 vCPUs, 1.875 GB memory, 1 GB storage
- Worker: 0.5 vCPUs, 1.875 GB memory, 1 GB storage
- Autoscaling worker: from 1 to 3.

I would like to create different pools to separate my 5 systems. How do I define the number of slots in each pool? Suppose a pool has 1 DAG with 10 tasks (with 5/10 concurrent tasks). How many slots should I assign to each task?

DAG example: 
task1.x is ingestion of JDBC table; while task2.x is update of the corresponding BigQuery table.

[image: DAG example]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow pools are designed to avoid overwhelmed on external systems used by a group of tasks. For example, if you have some tasks in different dags which use a machine learning model API, a RDBMS, an API with quotas or any other system with limited scaling, you can use an Airflow pool to limit the number of parallel tasks which interact with this system.

In your case, you have two systems, JDBC database and BigQuery. You need to create just two pools, `jdbc_pool` and `bigquery_pool`, and assign all the tasks (form all the dags) which interact with the jdbc table to the first one and assign all the tasks which interact with biquery to the second one. For the slots, you can define them based on the performance of each system, and the computational weight of each task.

If you have a monitoring tool (prometheus, datadog, ...), you can run one of the tasks and watch the resources usage on your db, lets assume that it uses 10% of the resources, in this case you can create a pool with 8 slots to attend 80% of resources usage (you should avoid using 100% of the resources to avoid the problems when there is unexpected load). Then for the [pool slots](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html#using-multiple-pool-slots) of each task:

1. if all the tasks are similar, you can use `pool_slots=1` for all the tasks: max 8 parallel tasks with 80% of resources usage
2. if you have some tasks which are more complicated than the task you have tested (they use more than 10% of the db resources), you can use a higher value for `pool_slots` for these tasks based on the resources usage: assume there is a task which consumes 20% of the resources, you can use `pool_slots=2` only for this tasks and keep 1 for the others, in this case you can have 8 parallel simple tasks or 6 parallel simple tasks with this heavy task with 80% of resources usage in the two cases.

For `bigquery_pool`, you need to check what are the quotas, but I think you can use a high value without any problem where it is a very scalable serverless DWH.

If you just want to limit the number of executed tasks in each worker to avoid OOM problem for ex, you can set the [worker concurrency](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-concurrency) conf.
And if you want to limit the number of executed tasks in the whole Airflow server, you can set the [parallelism](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#parallelism) conf.